# How to do "UPDATE table SET COL = COL + 1"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I do this in EF Core 6:

```
int diff = 2;
var row = await db.Table.FirstOrDefaultAsync();  // foo = 3
row.foo += diff;
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

It translates to SQL `UPDATE Table SET foo=5`. If the database changes during my operation, it will set a wrong value.

I have heard that EF Core has collision prevention and will throw an exception in such a case, but if I use the SQL `UPDATE Table SET foo=foo+2` can I even avoid the collision? If so, how to write this is EF Core 6?

Comment: db.Table.Update(c => new Table { foo= c.foo + 2 });

Comment: If you prefer LINQ, It can be done by third party extensions only. Every changes in EF should go via `ChangeTracker`.

Comment: Normal collision detection is done by having the old values of the row in the where clause aka `UPDATE Table SET foo=newFoo WHERE PrimaryKey=id AND  foo=oldFoo`. If the returned affected rows count is null you know there was a concurrent change while editing the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make raw SQL queries, i.e. something you can execute, EF Core is maybe not the best, as EF Core is an entity tracking framework. But [it is supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).

You can also try [bulk updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating#bulk-updates), but they have the same issue when an entity is updated during writing back:

```cs
foreach (var item in context.Table)
{
    item.foo++;
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Note the text at the bottom:

> Unfortunately, EF doesn't currently provide APIs for performing bulk updates. Until these are introduced, you can use raw SQL to perform the operation where performance is sensitive:
> `context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("UPDATE [Employees] SET [Salary] = [Salary] + 1000");`

You could also make an old-fashioned ADO call

```cs
string queryString = "UPDATE [table] SET [foo]=[foo]+2";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

edit: note both `Execute[...]` calls return an `int` representing the number of lines affected.